# In Wagtail, how to deal with singleton pages?

Tags: django, wagtail

I am developing a wagtail website. There are some pages that have specific design that will exist on exactly one page (e.g. "who are we" with a list of pictures and bio, "how does it work" which integrates some very specific charts in a very specific way, the home page…).

Currently, for those pages, I am creating one model/template per page, but it's not perfect:

- The page has no dynamic content and the url can be chosen ahead of time. I could use a simple static html asset, it won't have the right url (it would be something like `domain.com/static/who-are-we.html` instead of `domain.com/who-are-we`)
- Non-technical editors are confused (why can I create more than 1 "who are we" page?)
- Since the page is a singleton, referring to it in other pages should be easy. But currently I have to add a field to other pages model and choose the page every time. That's a bummer since I know that there exist one and only one page "who are we", so I'd like to directly integrate it in the template and skip a field in my models.

Is there an idiomatic way to deal with this situation in Wagtail?

Comment: To prevent creating more than one of any page type you can add a `max_count = 1` property to the page model (see https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.models.Page.max_count)

Comment: Thanks I missed that! My questions on DX/workflow still stands though.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Dan Hayden, you can add `max_count = 1` to your page model to make sure only one can be created.

What I typically do for singleton pages like this (a legal page for example) is that I add add them to a [SiteSetting](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/contrib/settings.html). This way the page only needs to be set once in the settings area in the CMS admin.

### Setting model

```py
from django.db import models
from wagtail.admin.panels import FieldPanel
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSiteSetting, register_setting

@register_setting
class GlobalSettings(BaseSiteSetting):
    legal_page = models.ForeignKey("yourapp.LegalPage", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("legal_page")
    ]
```

### Accessing the setting in templates

```
{% load wagtailsettings_tags %}

{# legal_page can be empty so consider being defensive! #}
{% if settings.yourapp.GlobalSettings.legal_page %}
   {% with settings.yourapp.GlobalSettings.legal_page as legal_page %} 
      <a href="{{ legal_page.full_url }}">{{ legal_page.title }}</a>
   {% endwidth %}
{% else %}
  No legal page set
{% endif %}
```